# Do Not Call List Integration

Tags: civicampaign

I wish to integrate the US "Do Not Call" (DNC) list as either a service or as an imported list to verify my contacts are not on the list.

Somehow, in the course of research, I believe I encountered an extension that did this via the issued (DNC) SANS number.   And, same functionality offer call list creation, assignment of caller, etc... essentially, call enter functionality.

If anyone is aware, appreciated.